# How to log to a Redmine account using REST API

Tags: rest, post, request, redmine, redmine-api

I need see an example POST request to log in to a Redmine account. Thanks.

I am developing a shell for the Redmine system in my organization. This is a web application that uses an API key and "communicates" with Redmine using REST requests

Comment: For start you can take a look at official documentation... https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_curl